# MS ACCSS VBA PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I need to pivot a table based on the following:

```
ID | Level   
10 |   1 
10 |   2
10 |   2
10 |   3
10 |   3
11 |   3
```

To appear like this:

```
ID  | Level1 | Level2 | Level 3
10  |    1   |   2    |    2
11  |    0   |   0    |    1
```

In SQL SERVER, this is the code:

```
SELECT ID, [1] AS PL1, [2] AS PL2, [3] AS PL3
into Table2
FROM 
(SELECT ID, [Level]
FROM Table1 ) ps
PIVOT
(
COUNT ([Level])
FOR [Level] IN
( [1], [2], [3] )
) AS pvt
```

In MS ACCESS / VBA i am doing this but getting an error "run time error 3000 reserved error (-3002); there is no message for this error"

```
mysql2 = "Transform Count([Table1].[Level]) " _
        & " select [Table1].[ID], [Table1].[Level] " _
        & " INTO [Tabel2] " _
        & " FROM [Table1]" _
        & " Group By [Table1].[ID] " _
        & " PIVOT [Table1].[Level] "
dbs.Execute mysql2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, managed to get it up. Sharing just in case somebody needs it.

Problem is that the TRANSFORM can only work on SELECT, there should not be INTO as part of the whole query.

Resolution:

First, save that SELECT statement as a query WITHOUT INTO.

```
Transform Count([Table1].[Level]) 
select [Table1].[ID], [Table1].[Level] 
FROM [Table1]
Group By [Table1].[ID] 
PIVOT [Table1].[Level]
```

In the VBA script, make a table using the query:

```
  mysql2 = "select * into Pivot_Table" _
        & " from QueryName "
  dbs.Execute mysql2
```